# Push notification error InvalidRegistration in php code?

Tags: php, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have issue with push notification with php code I am already try many things but I am not found where is my mistake in code. It's show me error that InvalidRegistration. And I try many device id with I have in my old project which is working.

This is my php code for push notification.

```
$devicesId = 'eHRFURsiMfg:APA91bEISYn7wFGczYLfVtq4j3fso2vcjAIbX32ACEjNDOrj_3Ra-BQg49jfpuNGsFpS_ucp_tEujse9yow_yTREKHCRD_y7a1kZZmq38L-YsHVTCnf0kdDR8_yN2IxcRPJNmRMHmr37';

    $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

    $fields = array(
        'registration_ids' => array($devicesId),
        'data' => array("message"=>'Breaking news.'),
    );

    $headers = array(
        'Authorization: key='."AIzaSyBL20ZXbSqlHGt8bU4Isv7ziHvylHkW4oU",
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    if ($result === FALSE) {
        die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
    }

    curl_close($ch);
    echo $result;
```

Comment: InvalidRegistration means your that those device ids are invalid. It has to match the registration ids generated on the client side when the device registered. Have you tried checking those ids?

Answer (score 0):

Please re-look at your device_id and authorization key. following code is working properly. Try this.

```
// API access key from Google API's Console
define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', 'AIzaSyAJQWiK9w2UVsVCY8P8pnOr356bHero6eo');

// prep the bundle
$msg = array('message'  => 'You liked this message!',
             'title' => 'title');

$fields = array(
'registration_ids'  => array('APA91bGJ0n6nhpp4F6kfTuJd4vZlS53mR4KYyylUHIbglSfGTjp3WhOtM37zDfYSN5BQGSTifE_27cRKDiNZD6ioXVUbY_BEXRi6dOQRRNWCApGvGy2F4lonAOXXCzMc7OXU8ipzgMqv'),
'data'   => $msg);

$headers = array(
 'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
 'Content-Type: application/json');

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send' );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );

$result = curl_exec($ch );

curl_close( $ch );
echo $result;
```